# Azure SAML Error (Validation Errors: 1. Issue time is either too old or in the future)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, azure-active-directory, spring-saml

Getting below after few days of inactivity in my UI where i have implemented this. It seems like previous logged in date is getting saved in cache and with next logged in date is not matching.

**Error: A SAML error occurred
Validation Errors: 1. Issue time is either too old or in the future:2023-10-03T08:17:07.005Z**

My Dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml-dsl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M31</version>
    </dependency>
```

My Security config

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(GET, "/home").permitAll().antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/home");
    
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
        }
    
    }

My Application.yml

    security:
      require-ssl:true
    server:
        port: 8443
        ssl:
          enabled: true
          key-alias: spring
          key-store: classpath:saml/keystore.jks
          key-store-password: secret
       
    spring:
      thymeleaf:
        cache: false
        enabled: true
        prefix: classpath:templates/
        suffix: .html
      security:
        saml2:
          network:
            read-timeout: 10000
            connect-timeout: 5000
          service-provider:
            entity-id: dummybot-saml
            alias: dummybot-saml
            sign-metadata: false
            sign-requests: false
            want-assertions-signed: true
            single-logout-enabled: true
            encrypt-assertions: false
            name-ids:
              - urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent
              - urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
              - urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
            keys:
              active:
                name: sp-signing-key-1
    
            providers:
              - alias: enter-into-dummybot-saml
                metadata: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                skip-ssl-validation: true
                link-text: enter-into-dummybot-saml
                authentication-request-binding: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
```

Comment: Azure SAML SSO with spring boot can be implemented using the SAML2-core 2.0.0.M31 dependency. This dependency provides a library of classes and methods that can be used to configure and implement SAML SSO with Azure. The library provides support for SAML 2.0 protocol, which is the most widely used protocol for SSO. It also provides support for various authentication methods such as username/password, OAuth, OpenID Connect, and more. Additionally, the library provides support for various security protocols such as TLS, SSL, and Kerberos.